# Map values to separate col using conditional statement: python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to use a conditional statement to create a new column but I'm unsure on the best way to proceed.

Using below, I essentially have various `Items` that contain a specific `Direction` for a given point in time. I want to use the `ID` to provide the correct `Direction`. So match the values in Items and ID to determine the correct `Direction`.

I've manually inserted this below as `Main Direction` but will need to automate this. I then want to pass a conditional statement to `X`. Specifically, `if == 'Up'` then add 10, `if == 'Down'` then subtract 10.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({              
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],  
    'ID' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A'],      
    'Items' : ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B'],
    'Direction' : ['Up','Down','Up','Up','Down','Up','Up','Down','Up','Up','Down','Down'],           
    'Main Direction' : ['Up','Up','Up','Up','Down','Down','Down','Down','Up','Up','Up','Up'],    
    'X' : [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6],      
    })

df['Dist'] = [df['X'] + 10 if x == 'Up' else df['X'] -10 for x in df['Main Direction']]
```

intended output:

```
    Time ID All Direction Main Direction  X       Dist
0      1  A   A        Up             Up  1         11
1      1  A   B      Down             Up  2         12
2      1  A   A        Up             Up  3         13
3      1  A   A        Up             Up  4         14
4      2  B   B      Down           Down  6         -4
5      2  B   A        Up           Down  7         -3
6      2  B   A        Up           Down  8         -2
7      2  B   B      Down           Down  9         -1
8      3  A   A        Up             Up  3         13
9      3  A   A        Up             Up  4         14
10     3  A   B      Down             Up  5         15
11     3  A   B      Down             Up  6         16
```

Comment: Your Question has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `np.where`

```
df.X=np.where(df['Main Direction'].eq('Up'),df.X+10,df.X-10)
df
    Time ID Items Direction Main Direction   X
0      1  A     A        Up             Up  11
1      1  A     B      Down             Up  12
2      1  A     A        Up             Up  13
3      1  A     A        Up             Up  14
4      2  B     B      Down           Down  -4
5      2  B     A        Up           Down  -3
6      2  B     A        Up           Down  -2
7      2  B     B      Down           Down  -1
8      3  A     A        Up             Up  13
9      3  A     A        Up             Up  14
10     3  A     B      Down             Up  15
11     3  A     B      Down             Up  16
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do the Main direction column

```
df['testDirec'] = np.where(df['ID'] == df['Items'],df['Direction'],None)
df['testDirec'] = df['testDirec'].ffill()
```

Gives the same as Main Direction

```
    Time    ID  Items   Direction   Main Direction  X   testDirec
0   1       A   A       Up          Up              1   Up
1   1       A   B       Down        Up              2   Up
2   1       A   A       Up          Up              3   Up
3   1       A   A       Up          Up              4   Up
4   2       B   B       Down        Down            6   Down
5   2       B   A       Up          Down            7   Down
6   2       B   A       Up          Down            8   Down
7   2       B   B       Down        Down            9   Down
8   3       A   A       Up          Up              3   Up
9   3       A   A       Up          Up              4   Up
10  3       A   B       Down        Up              5   Up
11  3       A   B       Down        Up              6   Up
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any custom function with apply. If you're operating row-wise (e.g. need more than one column) you'll call this with axis=1, and it will pass a row. Otherwise you can just do `df['my_col'].apply(lambda x: do_something_to_x(x))` and it will pass values of the col. For your example:

```py
def calc_dist(row):
    if row['Main Direction'] == 'Up':
        return row['X'] + 10
    else:
        return row['X'] - 10

df['Dist'] = df.apply(calc_dist, axis=1)
```